# Most elegant way to read a file and operating on lines as bytes

Tags: java

I have a database dump file I need to operate on rawly. I need to read the file in, operating on it line by line, but I can't have the whole file in memory (they can be 10gb + theoretically).

I want to be able to read it and operate on each line individually as I go, until the end of the file. It has to be weird character friendly (can have all sorts of bytes in them).

Comment: Use the FileInputStream.  It gives you bytes, however many you want at a time.  You'll have to recognize the line breaks yourself, but I assume you will know what they look like...

Comment: Do you **know** the encoding of the database dump? Or does it really contain binary (non-textual) data?

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the old nio example [grep](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/Grep.java) and remove the pattern match if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

if the line break doesn't interest you can use BufferedReader#readLine() and convert the string back to a byte[]

the other way is to use a byte[] as buffer (has to be large enough for a line) and use InputStream#read(byte[]) to fill it with bytes. then you can search the buffer for linefeeds and work with part of the buffer. once you find no more linefeeds, move the data to the left via System#arraycopy() and fill the rest with new data through InputStream#read(byte[], int, int) and go on.

but be careful! depending on the encoding (e.g. unicode) one byte doesn't have to be one character